# Gutenberg: Simple block render in back-end

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I built a simple `div` block with guten-block.

All does what it should, but if I give the `div` a custom class, then its not rendered in the back-end.

How can I change this?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

/**
 * BLOCK: bootstrap-blocks
 *
 * Registering a bootstrap container
 */

import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/editor';
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

registerBlockType( 'div-block/main', {
  title: 'div',
  icon: 'index-card',
  category: 'bootstrap-blocks',
    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        return (
            <div className={ 'container' }>
                <InnerBlocks />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save( { attributes } ) {
        return (
            <div className={ 'container' }>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WP Admin editor area is styled using your theme's `editor-style.css` file - [details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style).

The admin editor using Gutenburg uses the same file, with some small caveats. Namely, it auto converts `body` in the CSS to `.editor-styles-wrapper` because the editor area is no longer loaded in an iframe (Classic Editor is/was loaded in an iframe) - [details](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/themes/theme-support/#editor-styles).

So directly to the point, add `add_theme_support('editor-styles');` to your `functions.php` file and then add your block's styles in your theme's `editor-style.css` file.

Comment: I found the answer by myself. Just add className instead of container and then its rendered.